# Not able to add Recipient and not able to print

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am using Selenium WebDriver+Java+TestNG

1. On my web page there is textbox, where I need to add Email address of recipient and click 'Add recipient button'
2. After I click on that button, that email address will be moved to a box (which is embedded in Select tag) below it.
3. After that Email is gets added to box, then it will be embedded in Option tag.
   I have two problem with this,

   3.a. Even after I have clicked Add recipient button, it is not moved to below box

   3.b. I was not able to print that email address.
   I am using

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.id("txtRecipients")).sendKeys("xx");
   driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='btnAddRecipient']")).click();
   ```

   To print I am using

   ```
   String myemail=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*             [@id='lstBoxAlertRecipients']/option")).getText();
   System.out.println("The output is :" +myemail);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is, you are able to write into text box and after you have clicked on AddRecipient button, it is not able to move to below box.

are you able to move it below box manually?

Comment: Which box? below box? , I am not clicking below box, I am directly using that box by identifying it using xpath and trying to get values stored in option tag, which is nothing but email address.

Comment: That below box is embedded in Select tag, and when I add a recipient email address by click on that button ,then that email address will be embedded in Option tag.